# How can I use Ruby to verify the cipher suites that a web server supports?

Tags: ruby, ssl, encryption

I would like to create an automated checker in Ruby that verifies the TLS cipher suites in use against a target host. I don't mind if I use a built in library or an external gem, but I can't find anything out there so far.

I would like to get back a simple list of the supported cipher suites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first answer was incorrect because I misread the question.  I believe this will do what you want, if not be a good starting point.  *I did not do a cleanup or refactor pass on this.*

```rb
require 'openssl'
require 'socket'

# it doesn't matter that this would give a 301, this isn't HTTP
hostname = 'google.co.uk'
port = 443

# we cannot directly get to the SSL socket using net/http because
# it is already gone when we get the response back and it doesn't
# remember it, so we have to interact with OpenSSL directly like you
# would with the CLI version: `openssl s_client -cipher "TLSv1.2" -host google.co.uk -port 443`

# keep track of which ones work
success = []

# get a list of our ciphers we know about
ciphers = OpenSSL::Cipher.ciphers

# try each one
ciphers.each do |cipher|
  puts "Trying: #{cipher} ..."

  begin
    context = OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext.new
    context.ciphers = [cipher.upcase]
    socket = TCPSocket.new(hostname, port)
    ssl_socket = OpenSSL::SSL::SSLSocket.new(socket, context)
    ssl_socket.connect

    puts "Negotiated Cipher: #{ssl_socket.cipher[0]}"
    puts "Remote Ciphers:"
    puts ssl_socket.ssl_version
    ssl_socket.close

    # if we get this far, it worked
    success << cipher.upcase
  rescue OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError => e
    # do nothing
  end
end


puts "All the ones that worked:"
puts success
```

I would check this against a host where you know what the answer is.

Comment: This almost works!

For some reason, setting the context.ciphers to [cipher.upcase] results in an array with four ciphers, the last of which is the one I tried to set.

    irb(main):032:0> context.ciphers = [cipher.upcase]
    => ["PSK-AES128-CBC-SHA256"]
    irb(main):033:0> context.ciphers
    => [["TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384", "TLSv1.3", 256, 256],     ["TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256", "TLSv1.3", 256, 256], ["TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256", "TLSv1.3", 128, 128], ["PSK-AES128-CBC-SHA256", "TLSv1.0", 128, 128]]

Comment: I don't think I noticed when I ran your test script, but the 'hit' for me is always TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 regardless of the cipher being tested. Is this the same for you @squarism? Is this may something to do with a different version of OpenSSL and/or Ruby?

Answer (score 0):

**This answer is incorrect as I read it wrong but used in my edit**

The openssl gem comes with Ruby standard library.  Here's an example of how to get what you want without installing anything but Ruby.

```rb
require 'openssl'

# returns an array, I am just printing here
# you could filter, map or transform
# this relies heavily on the native openssl installation of the host or image
# so really, this is a Ruby interface to OpenSSL

ciphers = OpenSSL::Cipher.ciphers
puts ciphers

puts "We seem to have #{ciphers.length} ciphers available."
```

Comment: This would show ciphers supported by Ruby. Asker wants to connect to an arbitrary host and see which TLS ciphers it understands

Comment: How do you specify the host, e.g. www.google.co.uk ?

Comment: You're right, I'm sorry.  I read the question completely wrong.  I'm adding another answer.